# Susceptibility of β-Thalassemia Heterozygotes to COVID-19

Tags: covid-19, hematology, hemoglobin

A recent study by medical researchers in Greece (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34441941/) concluded that β-Thalassemia Heterozygotes (carriers) are more susceptible to severe symptoms of COVID-19 as well as death.  I have scoured the internet and various research databases and can find no other studies that confirm this is true for β-Thalassemia carriers, but there have been multiple studies on β-Thalassemia Homozygotes (those with β-Thalassemia Major).  Millions of β-Thalassemia carriers around the world would be interested in the answer to this question.  I wouldn't be surprised if this is true because of the lower hemoglobin levels that β-Thalassemia carriers have, meaning they can sustain less blood oxygen loss before experiencing severe symptoms (COVID-19 leads to reduced blood oxygen levels and appears to lead to reduced hemoglobin levels).  Please provide your thoughts.